# Asp.net child object with two parents

Tags: asp.net, model, entity, relationship

Let s say i have two tables, "article" and "event". They both have comments so they both need access to the "comments" entity.

How do i declare this relationship? having two foreign keys in "comments" is problematic since one of the foreign keys will be null in every case.
Can i just not declare any foreign key? Is there a convention on how to deal with this situation?

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Comment> comments { get; set; }  
} 

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Comment> comments { get; set; }  
} 

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Article  article { get; set; }
    public Event event{ get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: "having two foreign keys in "comments" is problematic since one of the foreign keys will be null in every case" - a foreign key can be null...

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe consider a dedicated comment table per entity. One comment table for article and another for event. Especially if individual comments never apply to both articles and events.

However, there is nothing that prevents you from making a shared one with two FKs as you described.